# Why does `xargs` not work with `echo` but work with `ls`?

Tags: linux, bash, ls, xargs, echo

```
root@home:~$ ls
root@home:~$ echo abc > z1
root@home:~$ echo xyz > z2
root@home:~$ ls
z1  z2
root@home:~$ ls | xargs -I{} cat {}
abc
xyz
root@home:~$ echo z1 z2 | xargs -I{} cat {}
cat: 'z1 z2': No such file or directory
root@home:~$ echo "z1 z2" | xargs -I{} cat {}
cat: 'z1 z2': No such file or directory
```

**Why does** `xargs` **not work with** `echo` **but work with** `ls`**?**

Comment: `xargs` "works" with `ls`, but [this is not the way to go](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "z1 z2"` is producing a single-line string:

```
z1 z2
```

`ls` is producing two lines:

```
z1
z2
```

You can replicate its behavior with `echo -e`, which will print `\n` as newlines:

```
$ echo -e "z1\nz2" | xargs -I{} cat {}
abc
xyz
```

Comment: Also, the `-I` option to `xargs` makes it break its input into lines, rather than into words; `echo z1 z2 | xargs cat` would also work. (But `printf '%s\0' z1 z2 | xargs -0 cat` is the more robust way to do it, because null bytes cannot occur in filenames. `printf '%s\0' z1 z2 | xargs -0 -I{} cat {}` would also work.)